# Typing a function to replace objects' null values with undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-narrowing

How would you type a function that accepts any object and returns the same object just with all the `null` values set to `undefined`. It should work in strict mode enabled.

The function implementation looks like this

```
export const undefineNullValues = (obj) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj ?? {}).map(([key, value]) => {
      return value === null ? [key, undefined] : [key, value];
    })
  );
};
```

I have tried the following:

```
type Return<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[keyof T] extends null ? undefined : T[keyof T];
};

export const undefineNullValues = <T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T
): Return<T> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj ?? {}).map(([key, value]) => {
      return value === null ? [key, undefined] : [key, value];
    })
  );
};
```

But I get the error

```
Type '{ [k: string]: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Return<T>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try force with `as`.

```
type Return<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[keyof T] extends null ? undefined : T[keyof T];
};

export const undefineNullValues = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  obj: T,
): Return<T> => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj ?? {}).map(([key, a]) => [key, a ?? undefined]),
  ) as Return<T>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to trick the compiler. I want to type it properly, if it is possible.

Comment: looks like this is the only way to do it, since Object.entries is typed as [string, any].